# Match strings (multiple lines) in a webpage with preg_match() or preg_match_all()

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I have the following HTML output I want to match the data from it, tried with preg_match() and preg_match_all() with no success.

```
<td width="130" valign="top">
Jane Doe<br />
            101 Marisa Cir <br />
            Staten Island NY, 10309<br /><br>
```

I want to match the "address data" as:

> Jane Doe, 101 Marisa Cir Staten Island NY, 10309

I fetch the page with CURL. I tried with something like this with no success:

```
preg_match('~<td width="130" valign="top">(.*?[^<])<br /><br>~i', $str, $showme);
```

Comment: Looks related, but can you really say it's a duplicate? @Gordon

Comment: @bozdoz in this particular case yes. It is good enough because how to achieve what the OP is asking for has been asked and answered a hundred times before so closing against the canonical is fine. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104877/are-specific-questions-duplicates-of-general-ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the s modifier, as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  It makes it so that the dot matches new lines.  Because your text is over multiple lines, you need the s modifier.  You can use a regex like this:

```
preg_match_all('~"top">(.*?)<br />(.*?)<br />(.*?)<br /><br>$~s', $text, $matches);
```

And that should work.  See the codepad example [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4zovCh).

Comment: Tried what you said, still getting no data, I get empty Arrays: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: You see that the codepad example works though right? @xtmtrx Maybe there's something more to your situation?

Comment: Yes, the example works perfect, but when I fetch data from my webpage I get no result matched. Weird.

Comment: Regular Expressions can be tricky like that. Let me know if there are any updates to your situation @xtmtrx.

Comment: Working on it, I'll get back, your answer is right, should work because in the example works but not in the live test.

Comment: Just took a deeper look, seems my HTML page being unde IIS and Coldfusion prints out DOS formatted data with "^M" at the end of the line, could be that? All I tested lately was under Unix environment. How can I match a DOS carriage-return?

Comment: This is my skeleton of the script, in the header is the page I try to get data parsed from. http://codepad.viper-7.com/FyYxsV

Comment: Works now, had to remove the "$"

Answer (score 0):

`[^<]` will be saying match anything which is not `<`, so it won't accept the two `<br/>` at the end of each line. What happens if you try just:

```
preg_match('~<td width="130" valign="top">(.+?)<br /><br>~i', $str, $showme);
```

If you want to remove those `<br/>` tags afterwards you can replace them out.